# Story where mental disabilities are used as an advantage

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novella

This was a fairly old story, probably 1950s at the latest (since I believe I listened to it on [Librivox](https://librivox.org/)) It was fairly short, either a short story or novella.

There was some kind of recurring interstellar war with another species who were technologically inferior, but *really* good at negotiating and always managed to put loopholes to their advantage in the peace settlements that humans wouldn't notice. In the story the humans got together a group of patients with mental disabilities, such as acute paranoia, that allowed them to see all the loopholes when the other humans couldn't.

Comment: I could have sworn this has been asked here before, but my searching has failed to find any previous question.

Comment: A search also doesn't find any reference to Philip K. Dick's [Clans of the Alphane Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clans_of_the_Alphane_Moon), which has a loosely related theme. It definitely isn't the story being asked about here, but it seems worth mentioning: "On Alpha III M2, psychiatric diagnostic groups have differentiated themselves into caste-like pseudo-ethnicities. The inhabitants have formed seven clans: The Pares are people suffering from paranoia. They function as the statesman class."

Comment: Possibly the same story - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221705/remote-space-station-forced-to-negotiate-with-aliens-and-succeed-due-to-mental-q/240651#240651

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly **In Case of Fire** (1960) • short story by Randall Garrett

An ambassador selects a ditherer and a paranoid to negotiate a peace treaty.

Comment: More detailed answer available at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221705/remote-space-station-forced-to-negotiate-with-aliens-and-succeed-due-to-mental-q?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes! That's it!