# short story - outpost of misfits stops alien invasion

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alien-invasion

As a teen over 50 years ago I read a short story with this plot. A sort of loser commander was sent to run a remote outpost on a rock of a planet in our solar system, where all the staff had limitations of one sort or another. One couldn't make a decision, another kept asking the same question, another couldn't understand anything he heard, etc. Then an alien force from outside our system was spotted on its way - and they were notorious for being such strong negotiators that every planet they visited was taken over within a few days.

The path of the invaders was such that they would pass by the remote outpost days before they could be reached by the main government and it's crack team of people. So they sent a message to the loser commander to try and delay the aliens best he could until they could get there.

When the main force finally arrived they were befuddled. The aliens were just camped out, with a defeated look, and non agrressive. When the earth force asked the loser commander what happened he told the he set up a greeting based on his people's shortcomings - the aliens could not deal with a people that could not understand, kept asking the same questions, and most of all someone who just couldn't make a decsision in negotiations. He had turned his people's weaknesses into strengths......

Comment: This sounds a bit similar to the book being asked for in [Story where mental disabilities are used as an advantage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172562/story-where-mental-disabilities-are-used-as-an-advantage)

Comment: The style of story sounds like Eric Frank Russell, but I don't recognise the specifics.